# ¿Como puedo imprimir los datos correctamente en este programa de MergeSort en c++?

Tags: c++, array, ordenamiento, recursión, ordenar

Hice una publicación anterior, ya casi esta el programa. Es un organizador de tareas que te deja registrar 3 campos: Nombre de la tarea, descripción de la tarea y fecha de vencimiento. Se guardan en un .txt y solo nos queda un problema: al momento de imprimir la tercera opción (Ordenar por fecha de vencimiento) las "Ordena" pero no de la forma correcta, debería ser así:

```
Nombre:Prueba 1  
Descripcion:Prueba 1  
Fecha de Vencimiento:20231201   

Nombre:Prueba 2  
Descripcion: Prueba 2  
Fecha de Vencimiento:20231202     

Nombre:Prueba 3  
Descripcion:Prueba 3  
Fecha de Vencimiento:20231203  
  
Nombre: Prueba 4   
Descripcion: Esto es una prueba   
Fecha de vencimiento: 20231204
```

Sin embargo, lo hace de la siguiente forma (Se ocuparon 4 ejemplos):

```
Tareas ordenadas:   
Fecha de Vencimiento: Esto es una prueba
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento: Prueba 4
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento: Prueba 3
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento: Prueba 3
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento: Prueba 2
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento: Prueba 2
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento: Prueba 1
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento: Prueba 1
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento: 20231201
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento:
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento: 20231202
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento:
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento: 20231203
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento:  
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento: 20231204
------------------------
Fecha de Vencimiento:
------------------------
```

¿Alguien tiene una solución o algún consejo?

El código es el siguiente:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;
struct Tareas {
  string Nombre, Descripcion, FechaVencimiento;
};
char opc;

void Registro() {
  system("cls");
  cin.ignore();
  ofstream archivo;
  archivo.open("Tareas.txt", ios::app);
  do {
    Tareas NuevaTarea;
    cout << "¿Cómo se llama la tarea?" << endl;
    getline(cin, NuevaTarea.Nombre);

    cout << "Agrega una descripción para la tarea: " << endl;
    getline(cin, NuevaTarea.Descripcion);

    cout << "¿Cuándo se tiene que entregar? (YYYY/MM/DD)" << endl;
    getline(cin, NuevaTarea.FechaVencimiento);

    if (archivo.is_open()) {
      archivo << NuevaTarea.Nombre << "\n";
      archivo << NuevaTarea.Descripcion << "\n";
      archivo << NuevaTarea.FechaVencimiento << "\n";
      archivo << " \n";

      cout << "La tarea ha sido guardada con éxito\n" << endl;
    } else {
      cerr << "Error al guardar la tarea\n" << endl;
    }

    cout << "¿Deseas agregar otra tarea? [y/n]" << endl;
    cin >> opc;
    cin.ignore();

    system("cls");
  } while (opc == 'y' || opc == 'Y');
  system("cls");
  archivo.close();
}

void Lista() {
  system("cls");
  cin.ignore();
  string tarea;
  ifstream archivo("Tareas.txt");
  cout << "Mostrando lista de tareas registradas...\n\n";

  while (getline(archivo, tarea)) {
    cout << tarea << endl;
  }
  system("pause");
  system("cls");
  archivo.close();
}

void Busqueda() {
  system("cls");
  cin.ignore();
  string Clave;
  Tareas tarea;

  cout << "Ingresa la palabra clave: " << endl;
  getline(cin, Clave);

  ifstream archivo("Tareas.txt");
  while (getline(archivo, tarea.Nombre)) {
    getline(archivo, tarea.Descripcion);
    getline(archivo, tarea.FechaVencimiento);

    if (tarea.Descripcion.find(Clave) != -1) {
      cout << "Nombre: " << tarea.Nombre << endl;
      cout << "Descripción: " << tarea.Descripcion << endl;
      cout << "Fecha de Vencimiento: " << tarea.FechaVencimiento << endl;
    }
  }
  system("pause");
  system("cls");
}

bool compararFechas(const Tareas & t1,
  const Tareas & t2) {
  // Convertir fechas a formato numérico (AAAAMMDD)
  int fecha1, fecha2;
  stringstream(t1.FechaVencimiento) >> fecha1;
  stringstream(t2.FechaVencimiento) >> fecha2;

  return fecha1 < fecha2;
}

void Merge(vector < Tareas > & arreglo, int inicio, int mitad, int final) {
  int izq = mitad - inicio + 1;
  int der = final - mitad;

  vector < Tareas > izquierda(izq);
  vector < Tareas > derecha(der);

  for (int i = 0; i < izq; i++) {
    izquierda[i] = arreglo[inicio + i];
  }

  for (int j = 0; j < der; j++) {
    derecha[j] = arreglo[mitad + 1 + j];
  }

  int i = 0, j = 0, k = inicio;

  while (i < izq && j < der) {
    if (compararFechas(izquierda[i], derecha[j])) {
      arreglo[k] = izquierda[i];
      i++;
    } else {
      arreglo[k] = derecha[j];
      j++;
    }
    k++;
  }

  while (j < der) {
    arreglo[k] = derecha[j];
    j++;
    k++;
  }

  while (i < izq) {
    arreglo[k] = izquierda[i];
    i++;
    k++;
  }

}

void MergeSort(vector < Tareas > & arreglo, int inicio, int final) {
  if (inicio < final) {
    int mitad = inicio + (final - inicio) / 2;
    MergeSort(arreglo, inicio, mitad);
    MergeSort(arreglo, mitad + 1, final);
    Merge(arreglo, inicio, mitad, final);
  }
}

void leerTareas(vector < Tareas > & tareas, vector < Tareas > & tareas2) {
  ifstream archivo("Tareas.txt");
  Tareas tarea, tarea2;

  while (getline(archivo, tarea.FechaVencimiento)) {
    tareas.push_back(tarea);
  }
  while (getline(archivo, tarea2.Nombre) && getline(archivo, tarea2.Descripcion)) {
    tareas2.push_back(tarea2);
  }

  archivo.close();
}

void ordenarTareas(vector < Tareas > & tareas) {

  for (int i = 0; i < tareas.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < tareas.size(); j++) {
      if (tareas[i].Nombre > tareas[j].Nombre) {
        swap(tareas[i], tareas[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}

bool continuar = true;

int main() {
  char opcion;
  Tareas tarea;
  do {
    cout << "Menu de opciones:" << endl;
    cout << "1. Crear Tareas" << endl;
    cout << "2. Mostrar lista de tareas" << endl;
    cout << "3. Ordenar tareas (por fecha)" << endl;
    cout << "4. Búsqueda de tareas" << endl;
    cout << "5. Salir" << endl;
    cout << "¿Qué desea hacer?" << endl;
    cin >> opcion;
    switch (opcion) {
    case '1':
      Registro();
      break;
    case '2':
      Lista();
      break;
    case '4':
      Busqueda();
      break;
    case '3':
      vector < Tareas > tareas, tareas2;
      leerTareas(tareas, tareas2);
      cout << "Tareas ordenadas: " << endl;
      MergeSort(tareas, 0, tareas.size() - 1);
      for (const auto & tarea: tareas) {
        cout << "Fecha de Vencimiento: " << tarea.FechaVencimiento << endl;
        cout << "------------------------" << endl;
      }
      ordenarTareas(tareas);
      for (const auto & tarea: tareas2) {
        cout << "Nombre: " << tarea.Nombre << endl;
        cout << "Descripción: " << tarea.Descripcion << endl;
        cout << "------------------------" << endl;
      }
      break;
    }
  } while (opcion != '5');
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar el contenido del archivo? No entiendo para qué utilizas 2 variables `Tarea` dentro de la función `leerTareas`.

Answer (score 0):

Ordenar y mostrar no te va a funcionar correctamente nunca de la manera que lo estás haciendo.

Para leer las tareas, estás separando los datos de tu tarea en dos partes:

1. Por un lado la fecha:

   ```
   while (getline(archivo, tarea.FechaVencimiento)) {
     tareas.push_back(tarea);
   }
   ```
2. Por otro lado el resto:

   ```
   while (getline(archivo, tarea2.Nombre) && getline(archivo, tarea2.Descripcion)) {
     tareas2.push_back(tarea2);
   }
   ```

Acto seguido, para mostrar los datos, sólo muestras los datos de una de las partes de tus datos separados; así es normal que veas datos incompletos:

- Los objetos de la colección `tarea2` no tienen datos en el miembro `Tareas::FechaVencimiento`:

  ```
  for (const auto & tarea: tareas2) {
     cout << "Nombre: " << tarea.Nombre << endl;
     cout << "Descripción: " << tarea.Descripcion << endl;
     cout << "------------------------" << endl;
  }
  ```

  En otras palabras, `Tareas::Nombre` y `Tareas::Descripcion` son cadenas vacías.

---

Te propongo el siguiente cambio: trata tus datos como un objeto completo, no como una colección de datos no relacionados entre si. Para ello define un operador de comparación para el objeto `Tareas`:

```
struct Tarea {
  string Nombre, Descripcion, FechaVencimiento;
};

bool operator<(const Tareas &a, const Tareas &b)
{
  return std::tie(a.Nombre, a.Descripcion, a.FechaVencimiento) < std::tie(b.Nombre, b.Descripcion, b.FechaVencimiento);
}
```

Ya puestos, renombra tu objeto a singular (`Tarea`) ya que dicho objeto almacena una sola tarea, no varias. Añade también unos operadores para leer/escribir de consola o archivo, como este:

```
// Operador de salida por consola
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Tarea &t)
{
  return o << "Nombre: " << t.Nombre << '\n'
           << "Descripción: " << t.Descripcion << '\n'
           << "Fecha de Vencimiento: " << t.FechaVencimiento;
}
```

Con estos cambios deberías poder ordenar y mostrar tus datos sin los problemas que experimentas:

```
std::vector<Tarea> tareas;

for (int tarea = 0; tarea != 4; ++tarea)
{
    Tarea t;
    std::cout << "¿Cómo se llama la tarea?\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, t.Nombre);

    std::cout << "Agrega una descripción para la tarea:\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, t.Descripcion);

    std::cout << "¿Cuándo se tiene que entregar? (YYYY/MM/DD)\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, t.FechaVencimiento);

    tareas.push_back(t);
}

std::cout << "\n\nAntes de ordenar:\n";
for (const auto &t : tareas)
    std::cout << t << '\n';

std::sort(tareas.begin(), tareas.end());

std::cout << "\n\nDespues de ordenar:\n";
for (const auto &t : tareas)
    std::cout << t << '\n';
```

El código anterior [muestra la siguiente salida](https://tio.run/##rVPNjtMwED7XTzEUaTfRlv5tT012VysKtwUOCAmpEnIcb2qR2MGxuSAehmfYB0CiD1bGiZu0adFeyKXj@fnm@2amrCxfZYztdi@FZLlNOcSV0UJmt6TzGFvm/NAhFCZxWhz6vnNmlD70nAI9npbRPFNamA06CUYtM/CRYhL8IACVSZfLBgbeqSLRfAQrXjEtSiaUHMFbzjb0E5dMFIJLoyLyMyIkUSoHVXJNkVEcMCWrPeoFHcHROwmJ66S5sVo2DY3gAR3v@9HxUUc67vcMIe7qkrYuOa5LTuuQLCGTCbx3TFOlAedR0VykFEp8OZoqp6TG9gOHi1ZWHPQCPWHmSJiCOIZhw20JQ/cynqqzL9fyEpPbzyW39LdPsi050PSvulqn03Kgta0/szBChDRQUCEDR3lQy2quKa613IJxPxVudvCIgwlcfu2CG5hG3nxxA4sIrq7qV0gGiDRoRmEiNGtUpqypOf75/Xr7VCioOOQ5LSjktIG5W8thm55xkwvJm0EzgVvczyx0XHqY95nmGQUrnfhudFBS3eEvn8M/GPC5Jkjcbn/JtKaOByc5fLMccJSuub6D4DN@k4eHyWoVPtfrzEViejPscWmrzZeEsq@BQf8A19SjspZreS8Nr9yulU65pNrLq7fUXCO1RuExwtIvMexLMvs7ivYdKqVN4FkkPHN3MfLVYy7TIAyjs2RwdKX9r3T8n2eKV7rbfdCWJxQW5E2FGNjHbbqsnWQ@nV/P5tMF8UnXneFDrWfeGT7Uemad4UMz8hc):

```
Antes de ordenar:
Nombre: Prueba 4
Descripción: Esto es una prueba
Fecha de Vencimiento: 20231204
Nombre: Prueba 3
Descripción: Prueba 3
Fecha de Vencimiento: 20231203
Nombre: Prueba 2
Descripción: Prueba 2
Fecha de Vencimiento: 20231202
Nombre: Prueba 1
Descripción: Prueba 1
Fecha de Vencimiento: 20231201


Despues de ordenar:
Nombre: Prueba 1
Descripción: Prueba 1
Fecha de Vencimiento: 20231201
Nombre: Prueba 2
Descripción: Prueba 2
Fecha de Vencimiento: 20231202
Nombre: Prueba 3
Descripción: Prueba 3
Fecha de Vencimiento: 20231203
Nombre: Prueba 4
Descripción: Esto es una prueba
Fecha de Vencimiento: 20231204
```